# Limit of the product of two convergent sequences equal to the product of those sequences' limits

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that if $\left(s_n\right)$ converges to $s$ and $\left(t_n\right)$ converges to $t$, then $\left(s_n t_n\right)$ converges to st. Is the following correct?

Consider arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. There exists $N_1 s.t. n>N_1 \implies |s_n-s|<w-s$, where $w\in \{z\in \mathbb{R}: z>\max\{s,0\} \}$. There exists $N_2$ s.t $n>N_2 \implies |t_n -t|<\frac{\epsilon}{2w}$. There exists $N_3$ s.t. $n>N_3 \implies |s_n-s|<\frac{\epsilon}{2|t|+1}$. So $n>\max\{N_1, N_2, N_3\} \implies |s_n t_n-st|=|s_n t_n -ts_n+ts_n-st| \leq |s_nt_n-ts_n|+|ts_n-st|=|s_n||t_n-t|+|t||s_n-s|<|w|\frac{\epsilon}{2|w|}+|t|\frac{\epsilon}{2|t|+1}=\epsilon$.

Comment: Not sure who closed but I thought 'proof checking' were valid questions and it is not really possible to be a duplicate unless it's literally the same person writing the same proof and asking for it to be checked. Obviously a correct proof of this lemma exists written somewhere - so it seems silly to close on essentially those grounds. The point of the Q. is for the writer of the proof to be specifically told where this attempt has errors. (I am a big believer that math students getting critiquing on writing is very important)

Comment: @T_M I concur with your opinion. Is my attempt correct?

Comment: The main mathematical issue is that if $t$ is zero, we cannot consider $\epsilon/2|t|$. The other issues are more cosmetic... I wouldn't write things like $|s_n - s| < w-s,w > \max\{0,s\}$ with just a comma separating two statements; it's a bit ambiguous and hard to read. You mean something like "where $w$ is some number satisfying $w > ...$". But having said that, the introduction of $w$ is a bit unnecessary. e.g. Remember that you can always arrange something like $|s_n - s| < 1$ and try to go from there.

Comment: @T_M Does my edit address your concerns?

Comment: Not fully, I'm afraid. Now $t = -1$ is an issue. You want $(|t| + 1)$, I assume? Again: I am of the opinion that the introduction of another letter $w$ is unnecessary and ultimately harder to read than if you just got rid of it altogether. It's almost always better just to be explicit. Maybe just literally use $(\max\{s,0\} + 1)$ if that is a number that will work.